# SQL query last transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, repeat

[image]

You can't see on the image but I have many till_id numbers. (1,2,3,4,5).

What I want to do is just showing the last "trans_num" without repeating the till_id.

For example:

```
till_id    trans_num
1          14211
2          14333
3          14555
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to do this is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.trans_date = (select max(t2.trans_date)
                      from t t2 
                      where t2.till_id = t.till_id
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select till_id  ,trans_num, max(transdate) from tableA
group by till_id  ,trans_num
```

Filter the columns you need in outer query or write inner query in where condition

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by till_id in subselect

```
Select a.till_id a.trans_num
from your_table as a
where (a.trans_date. a.till_id)  = (select max(b.trans_date), b-till_id
                              from your_table as b
                              group_by b.till_id
                            );
```